# How to overcome Drawback of Inverse Document Frequency (IDF)

Tags: search-engine, information-retrieval

Please tell me how to overcome the problem of negative weighting in IDF. Can someone give a small example?

Comment: Negative weighting? How should that happen?

Comment: @qqilihq IDF shows potentially major drawbacks when using it for terms appearing in more than half of the corpus documents. These terms' IDF is negative, so for any two almost-identical documents, one which contains the term and one which does not contain it, the latter will possibly get a larger score. This means that terms appearing in more than half of the corpus will provide negative contributions to the final document score.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IDF is defined as N/n(t) where n(t) is the number of documents that a term 't' occurs in and N is the total number of documents in the collection. Sometimes, a log() is applied around this fraction.

Please observe that this fraction N/n(t) is always >= 1. For a word which appears in all documents, a likely case of which is the English word "the", the value of idf is 1. Even if a log is applied around this fraction, the value is always >= zero. (Recall the graph of the log function which monotonically increases from -inf to +inf with log(x)<0 if x<1 log(1)=0 and log(x)>0 if x>1).

So, there's no way in which a standard definition of idf can be negative.

Answer (score 2):

The answer given by Debasis is entirely correct. Negative idf might still resulf, however,  if a small +1 term is added to the divisor to avoid divide-by-zero errors. One source that suggests this is the [Wikipedia article on tf-idf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf). The problem is that the LOG operation then results in a negative value if the occurrence count n(t) is equal to the count of documents N (i.e. it appears in all of them). I just ran into this issue when implementing tf-idf on a toy problem, where a document count N = 3 and an occurrence count of 3 would ordinarily = 0, but resulted in an idf of -0.287682072451781 because of the +1 correction term increased the divisor to 4, > than the count of documents. Perhaps this was the culprit behind the negative weights the O.P. experienced. I figured I'd post this just in case someone else runs into this initially baffling problem again. The fix is simple: remove the +1 term and find another way to avoid divide-by-zero errors.